# Working on custom wordpress theme and having trouble with next: wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add my own theme to wp themes.  But I am getting next error:
http://something.comget_template_drectory_uri/css/non.css?ver=1.0.0
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Is it something wrong with path to my documents?

Next is path to functions.php:
/home/something/something.com/wp-content/themes/something/functions.php

and next to file which I want to enqueue:
/home/something/something.com/wp-content/themes/something/css/nono.css

```
<?php

    function nono_scrypt_enqueue (){

    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle',get_template_drectory_uri.'/css/nono.css',array(),'1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs',get_template_drectory_uri.'/js/createO.js',array(),'1.0.0', 'all' );    
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nono_scrypt_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is a typo in there (d**i**rectory) and also [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) is a function, so it will only work if you bring the brackets. 
Change `get_template_drectory_uri` to `get_template_directory_uri()` and it should work.

Comment: I get this after i have added brackets:Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_drectory_uri() in /home/something/something.com/wp-content/themes/something/functions.php on line 5

Comment: Thank you for the brackets. And i have forgot also "i" in  d"i"rectory.